# Looking for a boolean SwiftUI construct

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is there such a construct in `SwiftUI` which will allow me to write something like this, based on a boolean variable called flag:

```
ZStack {
    test flag {
        Text("Today is sunny")
    }
    test !flag {
        Text("Today is rainy")
    }
}
```

If flag is true "Today is sunny" will be displayed, otherwise "Today is rainy" will show up.

The construct:

```
.sheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>) {...}
```

is somewhat close to what I want but not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal `if` conditions.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var flag = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if flag {
                Text("Today is sunny")
            } else {
                Text("Today is rainy")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With flag defined as State, the if statement will get live update furthermore

Comment: What if OP just want to pass in the state?

Comment: Your solution is correct. Just letting him know, it would work in State aswell.

Comment: I works. I think I had tried something like that before which didn't work. Maybe a mistake ...  The problem with mixing States and Bool is that we get errors about incompatibility between Bool and Binding<Bool> or something similar....

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you want to achieve. Here is the simplest

```
ZStack {
   Text("Today is \(flag ? "sunny" : "rainy"))
}
```

Comment: True, this is the simplest, but limited to the simple case of a text (as presented in my post to make the question simple), but I want to be able to use the method when replacing the Text by a VStack or any other thing more complex that a Text.